# What happens under the hood in if statement?

Tags: python

What goes on under the hood in `if` statement? For example:

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3]
str_ = ''

if str_ or list_:
    # do something
```

Can we say that implicitly something like this happens?

```
if bool(str_ or list_) is True:
    # do something
```

Comment: Yes. It evaluates the truthiness, and checks if the expression after the `if` is `True`. Note that `or` also evaluates truthiness.

Comment: Semantically, they're the same, but the byte code generated in each case differs.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: yeah, I guess that is because `bool` can be overwritten, so Python can not optimize this away.

Comment: read the text below [boolean-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) - several things in python are considered `False`: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets)

Comment: If you make a custom class, you can define `__nonzero__` in Python 2 or `__bool__` in Python 3 to override what happens during an if statement.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, and even removing the `bool`, keeping the `is True` still forces the explicit comparison.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - That doesn't seem right. `('' or [1,2,3]) is True` returns `False`. Or do I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Robᵩ: well `'' or []` is `[]`, and this is not `True`. `is` means reference equality, so the `bool(..)` is necessary for *semantical* equivalence. The point is, that if we could guarantee that `bool` will keep a reference to the builtin `bool` function, then Python could optimize `if bool(<expr>) is True` to `if <expr>:` but since this can not, we can not do it. `<expr> is True` is different from `bool(<expr>) is True`, since `is True` checks if that object is the `True` object, not if the object has *truthiness* `True`.

Comment: @Robᵩ I was only pointing out that nothing is optimised away by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of

```
str_ or list_
```

is surprisingly **neither** `True` **nor** `False` - it's simply `str_` or `list_` :-)

More precisely - from [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting
>   value is returned.

Then, for evaluation in the `if` statement:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following
>   values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including
>   strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects
>   can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.

---

So, in your particular case, `str_` is empty, so its boolean value is interpreted as `False`, and

```
str_ or list_
```

will evaluate to the value of the variable `list_`, i. e. to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Then

```
if [1, 2, 3]:
```

is interpreted as

```
if True:
```

because `[1, 2, 3]` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

if you say

```
a = 0
b = None
c = 123
d = 'aaa'
zzz = a or b or c or d
```

then `zzz` is equals to `123`. So if evaluates expression and operates on that answer. Since Python takes non empty strings, lists, non `None` values, not zero numbers - as `True` then whole system follows bool algebra.